# Flutter: Error: Error when reading '-': The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: flutter

I have added all the path environment variables and the flutter doctor command does not give any errors. However, when I try to run the command **Flutter Run** inside my project, I get the following error:
[image]

I have added all the path variables correctly. I get the same error if I try to run this project from within Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my project was nested very deeply. SO it's better to keep you project outside. It's works after that.